# push from local branch to different remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, remote-branch

I have 2 branches named `developer` and `Current` on remote. In local I'm working on branch `developer` and I push my changes to remote `developer`. The question is, **how can I push from local `developer` to remote `Current`**?

I have tried these:

```
git push origin Current -f
// error:
// src refspec Current does not match any.
// failed to push some refs to ...

// and this one too:
git config push.default upstream
git push origin Current -f
// error: same as the first try

// and this one too:
git branch --set-upstream-to developer origin/Current
// or:
git branch --set-upstream-to developer Current
// error: fatal: branch 'Current' (or 'origin/Current') does not exist
```

Comment: `git branch (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]` - your syntax is screwed up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do:

```
git push origin developer:current
```

This will push branch `developer` from your local repo to branch `current` on the remote repo. In case you are overwriting changes on branch current, you will need to use the `-f` flag as well.

FWIW, doing a `git push origin :current` (note the `:` before `current`) will delete the branch `current` from the remote.

Comment: FYI this pushes `developer` to `current` without making `current` the upstream branch of `developer`. Ie. if `developer` is set to track `origin/developer`, running this command will not change that. Personally, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

While on your `developer` branch, try `git push -u origin Current`.  `-u` is shorthand `--set-upstream`.  It looks like using `--set-upstream` with `git branch` requires the upstream branch to already exist; this isn't the case when using it with `git push`.