# how to push different branches to different remote repos in one repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a local repo and it has some branches, e.g. `branch1`, `branch2`..

I want to push the branches to different remote repos, how?

Comment: This is about configuring your git remotes. I would recommend learning about them. It will help you in the long run. Stackoverflow already has many posts that can help you in this. [This can help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28300580/2915738). And also [For more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617350/2915738)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
git push https://repo.one/there branch1
git push https://repo.two/elsewhere branch2
```

If you want to shorten your commands, you can predefine the remote destinations:

```
git remote add one https://repo.one/there
git remote add two https://repo.two/elsewhere
```

Then the commands can be shortened to

```
git push one branch1
git push two branch2
```

You can also set the default push destinations:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=one/branch1 branch1
git branch --set-upstream-to=two/branch2 branch2
```